# Where to start with this precalculus question about logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I came across a question I guess I wasn't entirely prepared for in my precalculus textbook. In the question, I have to solve for T in $\ln(T-21) = at + b$. First, I multiplied by $\ln21$, but I realized that wasn't right. Now I don't know where to start. I'm sure the answer is right in front of my face, but I'm new to logarithms, so I don't see it. What's the first step in isolating T in this equation?

Comment: Apply $e^x$ on both sides and remember that $e^{\ln(x)}=x$. You get that $T-21=e^{at+b}$.

Comment: Adding to what @user85667 said, in general, most functions have an "inverse", which I tell my students is like an "undo", so you always have to ask yourself, "what is the undo operation for what I'm looking at".  The "undo" of $+$ is $-$, the "undo" of multiplication is division.  Likewise, the undo operation for $\ln(x)$ is $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\ln(T-21) = at+b$$ $$\implies e^{\ln(T-21)} = e^{at+b}$$
$$\implies T-21 = e^{at+b}.$$

To get the second equation from the top, what was used is the following: If $X=Y$ then $e^X=e^Y$.